# SQL array agg and joins

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, knex.js, array-agg

In my Postgres database, I have 3 tables. One for `users` one for `comments` and one to map the two `user_comment_map`. Here's how the tables look:

```
users
| id | name | age |
|----|------|-----|
| 1  | user | 20  |


comments
| id | mood  | subject | content         | created_at               |
|----|-------|---------|-----------------|--------------------------|
| 1  | happy | funny   | here is content | Tue Sep 27 2016 13:44:19 |
| 2  | silly | cool    | more content    | Tue Sep 27 2016 14:44:19 |

user_comment_map
| id | user_id | comment_id |
|----|---------|------------|
| 1  |        1|           1|
| 2  |        1|           2|
```

I'm trying to write a SQL query that results in the following object:

```
[{
  id: 1,
  name: "user",
  age: 20,
  comments: [
    {
      id: 1,
      mood: "happy",
      subject: "silly",
      content: "here is content",
      created_at: "Tue Sep 27 2016 13:44:19"
    }, 
    {
      id: 2,
      mood: "silly",
      subject: "cool",
      content: "more content",
      created_at: "Tue Sep 27 2016 14:44:19"
    },
  },
  {...}
]
```

I tried using `joins` and `array_agg` but I can't get the data in that format. Any help would be much appreciated. Note: I'm also using knex to build queries but I don't think that knex can handle stuff like this without resorting to `knex.raw`

Comment: Did you forget `users.age` in the result or do you omit it on purpose? Do you need `json`, `jsonb` or the exact text representation displayed as result? and please *always* declare the Postgres version in use.

Comment: Yeah. I went ahead and made edits. Also realized that I just need to sequel query to return an array of user objects with comment data nested in each user.

Comment: Are you going to disclose your version of Postgres (`SELECT version();`) and the desired data type for the result?

Comment: It's Postgres 9.5. My server is written in Node so when I run the sql query, it should return an array of user objects. Each user object will have an array of comment objects associated with it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should do it:

```
SELECT
    json_build_object(
        'id',id,
        'name',name,
        'comments',(
            SELECT json_agg(json_build_object(
                'id', comments.id,
                'mood', comments.mood,
                'subject', comments.subject,
                'content', comments.content,
                'created_at', comments.created_at
            ))
            FROM user_comment_map JOIN comments ON comment_id=comments.id
            WHERE user_id=users.id
        )
    )
FROM users
WHERE id=1;
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Answer to updated question

Without involving `json`. Just plain Postgres row and array types. And return all rows with all columns from `users` and `comments`:

```sql
SELECT ARRAY(
   SELECT t
   FROM  (
      SELECT u.*
          , (SELECT array_agg(c)
             FROM   user_comment_map uc
             JOIN   comments c ON uc.comment_id = c.id
             WHERE  uc.user_id = u.id
            ) AS comments
      FROM   users u
      ) t
   );
```

Using an [ARRAY constructor](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ARRAY-CONSTRUCTORS) on a subquery should be simplest and fastest.

But the result is an array of anonymous records. You probably do *not* want that. I suggest to rethink your approach.

#### Answer to original question

To return the result displayed as data type **`json`** (omitting `users.age`), [`to_json()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-CREATION-TABLE) on the alias of a subquery should be simplest and fastest.
Works in Postgres **9.2** or later:

```sql
SELECT to_json(t)
FROM (
   SELECT u.id, u.name        -- manual selection from from table users
       , (SELECT json_agg(c)  -- use table alias of comments to wrap whole row
          FROM   user_comment_map uc
          JOIN   comments c ON uc.comment_id = c.id
          WHERE  uc.user_id = u.id
         ) AS comments
   FROM   users u
   WHERE  u.id = 1
   ) t;
```

This query returns *whole* rows from `comments` and picks up on added / removed columns if you should change the table layout. But you have to maintain your selection of columns from `users` manually.

To get the **actual text representation** displayed (data type `text`), you can use [`jsonb_pretty()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE) in Postgres **9.5** or later:

```sql
SELECT jsonb_pretty(to_jsonb(t))
FROM (
   SELECT u.id, u.name
       , (SELECT jsonb_agg(c)
          FROM   user_comment_map uc
          JOIN   comments c ON uc.comment_id = c.id
          WHERE  uc.user_id = u.id) AS comments
   FROM   users u
   WHERE  u.id = 1
   ) t;
```

I am using `jsonb` functions here since `json_pretty()` only takes `jsonb`.

Comment: I really appreciate the answer. It doesn't need to return json. just an array of user objects. Each user contains their associated tweets

Comment: This is awesome! Thank you so much!